# Converting 8-bit ASCII character to byte

Tags: java, character-encoding, ascii

I can't believe I'm having a hard time with this, but so far haven't found the answer: Let's say I have a Java `char` (or a 1-character `String`) and I want to convert it into a `byte` of ASCII. How do I do this?

I know I could look up the decimal value of the ASCII character and create a byte from that, but it seems like there should be a simple conversion. I found what seems to be the answer for byte *arrays*:

```
byte[] asciiArray = "SomeString".getBytes( StandardCharsets.US_ASCII );
```

but not for just a single byte. Something like:

```
byte asciiA = <some conversion function>('A');
```

Comment: Are you looking for `(byte) 'A'`?

Comment: A Java `char` is not a byte.  It is 16-bit Unicode and must be encoded with a particular external representation, such as UTF-8.  Some "ASCII" characters will result in more than one byte output.

Comment: When you specify 8-bit do you really mean to include extended ASCII (0x80-0xFF)?  If so then it's not possible to convert all characters to single bytes, as some of them may encode as 2 bytes in UTF-8,  The question is unclear.

Comment: I think your first way is much clearer. You are taking a String (sequence of Unicode base codepoints each followed by zero or more "combining characters"), reducing them down to the ASCII characters set, replacing ones that have nothing similar in ASCII with '?' and encoding that in ASCII code units (bytes). Note: if prefer an exception instead of a replacement, you can code for that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 7-bit ASCII. So is `(byte) 'A'` foolproof for that?

Comment: @RobertLewis If you're only dealing with standard (7-bit) ASCII, yes, `(byte) 'A'` will work. Just remember that if your characters are outside that range, you'll get nonsense out.

Comment: Amazing how much discussion this seemingly simple question has evoked. And it seems to have highlighted a few misconceptions along the way. Anybody know of a DEFINITIVE explanation of how Java handles bytes, chars, and Strings?

Comment: The Java documentation is quite good. See [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html). Unicode has some [esoteric characteristics](http://joconner.com/iterating-java-characters/) but is less confusing if you forget about ASCII first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the character in the range U+0000 to U+007F, it would be one UTF-16 code unit (char), and also in the ASCII character set, and that UTF-16 code unit would have the same value as the ASCII code unit.

You might want to add a guard because (byte)'½' wouldn't give you anything useful.

Comment: Actually `(byte) '½'` would, but `(byte) '⅓'` would not.  0xbd will fit in a byte, but 0x2153 will not.

Comment: @VGR Ah, yes, it would be the ISO 8859-1 encoding for '½'. But, it would be nonsense to call it ASCII.